# different name and different IP on a single m/c

Tags: multi-homed

I am just a beginner in ip domain etc..I had two questions: 
if I have configuration on "same" Machine(win or lin) in host file like:

m/c name  :     IP(Example)

mac1.net.com   10.124.77.10 
and
mac2.net.com   10.124.77.11

We can say "different name and different IP on a single m/c". Will some application fail or will i get ipconflict  if i/some application tries to access this m/c .

Secondly,If i have  "IP:port-combination" 10.124.77.10:5650 occupied by some process XYZ ,will another process ABC  be able to use 10.124.77.11:5650

Comment: What does m/c stand for?

Comment: @JeffFerland Master of Ceremonies. Or mass divided by the speed of light.

Comment: i guess it stands for machine/computer..  @shashank: Please elaborate...

Comment: m/c = machine ,sorry for confusion

Answer (score 1):

> We can say "different name and different IP on a single m/c". Will some application fail or will i get ipconflict if i/some application tries to access this m/c .

I don't know what m/c stands for, but having a machine with multiple addresses assigned to it is not uncommon.

> Secondly,If i have "IP:port-combination" 10.124.77.10:5650 occupied by some process XYZ ,will another process ABC be able to use 10.124.77.11:5650

If your processes are bound to those specific interfaces, then yes. Processes can also bind to a wildcard of a given port on all interfaces, though. It depends on your configuration.

Comment: m/c = machine ,sorry for confusion

Comment: ok... so by above discussion we can have:
process1 running on 10.124.77.10:5056 .....

and
process2 running on 10.124.77.11:5060.....
(means, different name and different IP on a single computer/machine )

Comment: @shashank Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @shashank Don't forget to accept answers that you feel have addressed your question. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

```
We can say "different name and different IP on a single m/c". 
Will some application fail or will i get ipconflict if i/some application tries to access this m/c .
```

No, this is a common scenario.

```
Secondly,If i have "IP:port-combination" 10.124.77.10:5650 occupied by some process XYZ ,will another process ABC be able to use 10.124.77.11:5650
```

This depends on your scenario. Usually, you are not able to use the same port twice to listen on with different applications. In Windows 7/2008 R2 there is a concept called Port Sharing (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772001.aspx) which allows for several Communication Foundation applications to share a port. The same holds true for web servers, where different "web applications" can share a common port (usually `http/80` or `https/443`)